# rails mailer generates html and text in the same mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a method in mailer controller that send an email notification after each message was created on the platform.

```
MailerClass.send_mail_notification(to, @conversation).deliver_now
```

I wrote the method, wrote the views (in html and plain text).

```
MailerClass

def send_mail_notification(to, @conversation)
 subject = ..
 mail to: to,
  subject: subject,
  content_type: 'text/html'
end
```

However, when the mail was delivered in test, both the plain text and html version are put in the same html tab of the mailcatcher.

```
----==_mimepart_5e78cae1e1672_73fb2187fbc2829035 Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit # Hi ..., 

======================= 
there was a new message from ... to ...: 
how are you 
Click here to see more: open interview 
----==_mimepart_5e78cae1e1672_73fb2187fbc2829035 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit 
----==_mimepart_5e78cae1e1672_73fb2187fbc2829035 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit #<InterviewRequest:0x00007f6430a062c0>

Hi ...,
there was a new message ...
---==_mimepart_...
```

What I noticed was that the mimepart are the same for both type. Does it make mailcatcher to recognise those two as the same mail? how to generate different mimetype for plain text and html so that they are separated?

Anyone having similar situation or having any idea on this?
Thanks,